# When creating a box and whiskers diagram in Excel, the percentages are off by 10x. How can I fix this?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have some values that I wish to use a box and whisker's diagram. The values are percentages above a certain standard value, so percentage is the appropriate axis, but Excel is displaying 10 times the orignial values.

Most of the values are around +45% but a couple are outliers at 200+%.

The picture of the axis and my format settings will explain it best.

Image of axis and formating settings:
[image: Image of axis and formating settings]

Answer (score 1):

Your values are off by a multiplier of 100, not 10.

Excel doesn't take the same numerical values which you see in cells and just use them in the chart, but actually interprets percentage (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentage).

When you enter 1 in a cell, it equals to 100% (same if you play around with number formats in cells). 1% is 0.01 and so on. You need to make sure your values are formatted correctly.

Comment: OK that makes sense. But what percentage are they referring to? Percentage of the sum values?

Comment: "Percentage of the sum values?" - I suppose it's your original data interpreted as percentage ( x => x*100 %), but it's different to answer it without seeing your source data.